# how to use react-big-calendar onRangeChange option

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsJVY.png)

i want don't move calendar month so use this code

```
const FullCalendar = (props) => {

  const { calendarInfos, height, dateInfo } = props

  const { selectDate } = dateInfo

  const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

  return (
    <>
      <CalendarCss />
      <Calendar
        toolbar={false}
        popup={false}
        localizer={localizer}
        culture='ko'
        views={['month']}
        events={calendarInfos}
        defaultDate={new Date(moment(selectDate))}
        startAccessor="start"
        endAccessor="end"
        onRangeChange={(e)=>{console.log(e)}}
        style={{
          height: height + 'px',
          width: '100%',
        }}
        components={
          {
            event: (e) =>
              (
                <FullCalendarEvent
                  event={e}
                />
              )
            ,
          }
        }
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

but there is an error in this code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUYeW.png)

how to use react-big-calendar option onRangeChange

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-onRangeChange), it depends on the view (sorta).

```js
const onRangChange = (Range: [Date]) => do something

// or, the more likely

const onRangChange = ({start: Date, end: Date}) => do something
```

Supposed to use the second type for all builtin views, so unsure when that first type would qualify...

If you're trying to restrict it from moving month to month, better option is to use the controlled `date` prop and do some check to determine wether you set it or not.